# How can I create path variable from title?

Tags: java, spring, url, path-variables

I have a web application created with Java Spring MVC. So when a user want to read a article, s/he goes to [www.example.com/articles/{id}](http://www.example.com/articles/%7Bid%7D). I want to create path variable with title. For example: [www.example.com/articles/here-meaningful-title,id](http://www.example.com/articles/here-meaningful-title,id)

Edit: Another example is this page use my title as path variable:

www.stackoverflow.com/questions/37785513/how-can-i-create-path-variable-from-title

Are there any library to do it? Also should i save this url variable in DB or calculate it each time?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you @selva I am trying to get used to it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how I'd do this, but as a wild guess one solution could be to add a ViewData to wherever you assign your article header at,

```
ViewData["ArticleHeader"] = articles.name; // Or something like this, whatever it looks like in your code
```

Then on the link to the specific article, call it like this:

```
<a href="Articles/@ViewData['ArticleHeader']/ID"> Article 001 </a>
```